# How to move agents in main towards agents inside other agents in AnyLogic?

Tags: agent, anylogic

In AnyLogic...I am building a model where an Agent A (living in Main) will move to Agent B (living inside another Agent C, such as a home) once Agent B sends A a message. 
I have troubles when setting the "initial location" of Agents B.
How can I point to his particular "home" (Agent C)?

I have tried:
"in the specified point": X = this.getLongitude() ...
"in the node": this

But no luck.
Any ideas? Does this make any sense?

Answer (score 0):

It can be implemented in several ways. The most common is flowchart-based: agent leaves flowchart at `Main` through `Exit` block. In On Exit action of `Exit` block, call:

`agentC.enter.take( agent );`

`AgentC` type should have `Enter` block. In properties of the block, specify the initial location of entering agent. `Enter` can be considered as "gates" of agents who enter from another space (like `Main`).

Answer (score 0):

Gregory talks about a possible 'architecture' for the communication and movement but, to answer at the more general level of agent movement and embedding:

If your Agent types are `AgentA`, `AgentB` and `AgentC` with embedding as you say (population of `AgentB`s in their 'home' `AgentC`) then every `AgentB` instance will automatically have a link (a **Link to upper level agent**) to the embedding `AgentC` called `agentC`.

So, when an `AgentA` receives a message from an `AgentB`, you can just do something like

`moveTo(sender.agentC)`

or

`jumpTo(sender.agentC.getX(), sender.agentC.getY())`

(The `sender` is a special keyword referring to the sending agent in "On message received" code blocks. `jumpTo` moves instantly to somewhere rather than moving with whatever speed the agent has. Unfortunately `moveTo` lets you specify another agent as the target but `jumpTo` has to use coordinates or nodes.)

See the following help sections:

- AnyLogic Help > Agent Based Modeling > Agent interaction >
  Communication between agents
- AnyLogic Help > Release Notes > What's new in previous releases >
  What's new in AnyLogic 7 >  Link to upper level agent [section]
- AnyLogic Help > Agent Based Modeling > Agent movement >
  Movement in Continuous Space